# WPF: Base class for converters "catches" Convert method

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, converters

I guess my question topic is a bit confusing. In short, what I want:

I have a lots of `Converters` in my application. Many of them do not implement the `ConvertBack` method. So I would like to have a `BaseConverter` class that offers a simple empty implementation of `ConvertBack` and all my other Converters to inherit from the `BaseConverter`.

My idea of the `BaseConverter`:

```
public class BaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing in this dummy implementation
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing in this dummy implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

And one of my crazy converters:

```
public class CrazyConverter : BaseConverter
{
    public new object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return ACrazyConverionOfTheValue(...);
    }
}
```

However, if I try it like this and use my `CrazyConverter`, I always end up in the `Convert` method of the `BaseClass`. My new `Convert`method is never called. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: So how are you actually using it in your XAML? Can you show that?

Comment: Just like this: `<Label IsEnabled="{Binding IsCrazy, Converter={StaticResource CrazyConverter}>...</Label>´

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the methods in your base class `virtual`, and your child classes should `override` them (instead of `new`).

```
public class BaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing in this dummy implementation
        return null;
    }

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing in this dummy implementation
        return null;
    }
}

public class CrazyConverter : BaseConverter
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return ACrazyConverionOfTheValue(...);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: You might also want to consider refactoring this to require that `Convert` be overridden by making the class and `Convert` abstract, like so:

```
public abstract class BaseConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public abstract object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture);

    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // do nothing in this dummy implementation
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That is working perfectly for me. I will use the abstract class approach.